# Why for some actions wifi is required (ie. cellular is not enough)?

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data

Synchronizing iCloud photo library and downloading apps over 100 MB both require wifi, ie. they are not permitted when on cellular.

Is this limit only for "convenience", so there wouldn't be surprises when the phone bill arrives? **Is there any official reason?** Or technical?

I'm asking this as my current cellular plan (LTE) consistently delivers better speeds than my current ADSL plan (= wifi) and I have plenty of headroom in my transfer quota.

Comment: Did my tether trick work for you? If so could you mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

That mechanism is in place to protect customers unaware of the data limits and to conserve the network's bandwidth, this means that everyone gets an equal share of the network. Although what I normally do is USB tether to my Mac then Wi-Fi share the USB connection then connect to that with my iPhone

Comment: But your sharing trick wouldn't help the device USB-tethered to Mac, wouldn't it? Only other devices on the network? (I've done similarly too: put up network hotspot on iPhone, then switched Apple TV to use the hotspot instead of "regular" wifi and then watch full hd Netflix over cellular—all the while I can't sync my photo library on the road…)

Comment: iPhone connects to Mac via USB >> Mac shares USB connection as Wi-Fi >> iPhone connects to Mac Wi-Fi.   This works for me

Comment: That's a solid advice—have to test sometime at home. However, it wouldn't help much on the road and is a bit of a hassle; but for some one-off down/uploads that need speed, it might be reasonable to go for the extra mile.

Comment: There are ways to force it but can't remember what they are a search for "force download o 100mb iPhone" on google might help